# can I specify individual webjobs in settings.job

Tags: azure-webjobs

I have a very simple webjob that does just one thing. In the settings.job, I run it every 5 minutes `{"schedule":"0 */5 * * * *"}`

Now I want to add a new webjob, but wants to include it in the same project. This new webjob will run every 2 minutes. Is it possible to specify individual webjob in settings.job? Or it is better to specify directly in the function? e.g.

```
public static void MyFunction([TimerTrigger("0 */2 * * * *",
                                            RunOnStartup = true)]
                              TimerInfo timerInfo,
                              TextWriter log)
```

Answer (score -1):

Yes, you can have multiple WebJobs in the same project. However to do the same you would need to use Azure WebJobs SDK Extension i.e. TimerTrigger.

More details on the extension can be found at URL
https://github.com/Azure/azure-webjobs-sdk-extensions#timertrigger

You may also find below blog useful which talks about "How to have a single project to hold multiple scheduled Azure Webjobs"

https://patrickdesjardins.com/blog/how-to-have-a-single-project-to-hold-multiple-scheduled-azure-webjobs

Thanks
Alok

Comment: Hi, I am asking about settings.job, not about multiple webjobs in a project

Comment: Hi, settings.job can have only one WebJob. So if there are two WebJobs, you would need two settings.job files.